# Can I customise the time shown in the datepicker?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, javascript, date-time

I have a scenario where users are to book sessions with date and time. Currently, I am trying two ways to enforce unique values for date and time.

I added a date picker. I added a formula to validate the date to be only Fridays. But I need the time to be customized such as only time are shown e.g. 2:30 or 3:30 or 4:30 to be selected from. If I can customize it in such a way, I can enforce unique values easily.

If not, I have created 2 columns; date picker with date only and time as a drop-down choice. But how can I enforce 2 columns to be a unique value?

Kindly advise, I am open to suggestions

**JavaScript:**

[image]

**HTML:**

[image]

Comment: While using Date and Time column, you can hide some options from time drop-down control using javascript on list forms.

Comment: Oh i see, I tried getting codes from online but it is not working

Comment: I added the codes and screenshot to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select[id$='DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']").children("option[value='00']").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Here `$` shows that ID of select `Ends With` specified value `DateTimeFieldDateMinutes`.

Also, you can add completed ID for drop-down selector(Add selector carefully to get the particular element only):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#selectID").children("option[value='00']").hide();
    });
</script>
```